# JSON Decode PHP (Curl vs File_Get)

Tags: php

Currently, I am trying to use the Twitch API to grab Twitch stats such as current viewers, Title, and more I am running into an issue with `@File_Get_Contents` when using this my request seem to be delayed or not getting them as quick as I refresh, i.e. I think the results may be cache'd.

For example here is my old code

```
$twitch = json_decode(curl_get_file_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'.$twitch_channel), true);
$display_name = $twitch['display_name'];
$game = $twitch['game'];
$status = $twitch['status'];
$url = $twitch['url'];
$avatar = $twitch['logo'];
$views = $twitch['views'];
$followers = $twitch['followers'];
```

The main issue with this is it didnt seem like it updated every time I refreshed, so I looked into using cURL for better results + I heard it's much quicker with load time!

Here is my current curl code

```
$requesturl='https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' . $twitch_username;
$ch=curl_init($requesturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cexecute=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$twitch = json_decode($cexecute,true);
$display_name = $twitch['display_name'];
$game = $twitch['game'];
$status = $twitch['status'];
$url = $twitch['url'];
$avatar = $twitch['logo'];
$views = $twitch['views'];
$followers = $twitch['followers'];
```

Comment: For the first code I meant `@file_get_contents` not `curl_get_contents`

Comment: there is no `viewers` in the code posted

Comment: The code you showed doesn't use the variables `bio`, `users` and `online`.  So where is the error log getting their names from?

Comment: @Dagon  -- LOL I feel like an idiot, sorry just got off a 10hr shift and trying to get this to work, any idea why its not display the data? for the other stuff

Comment: @BeetleJuice - I realized after posting it, I cant change it now those arent defined in the config.php yet due to the other stuff that is defined not displaying properly with the new curl usuage

Comment: What I mean is: PHP doesn't make up these names. You use them in code somewhere.  That's where we should start looking for the error. According to your log, this is in `API_Test.php` on lines 10, 14 and 15

Comment: @BeetleJuice I know those are old variables I havent brought over from the other config.ph

Comment: what happens when you echo `$cexecute`. is it empty? is it valid json?

Comment: @chiliNUT correct its just blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ultimnately I figured out what the issue was, it's XAMP Curl not working for whatever reason. It's setup properly in the PHP.ini, I have the Two .DLL in my Sys32. So I dont know why this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Your log is showing PHP Notice, You don't have any error. I change a lil bit your code to test it and It's working. So you're probably just no printing your vars.

[Check your code with a print_r online](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$twitch_username='tsm_dyrus';%5Cn$requesturl='https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'%20.%20$twitch_username;%5Cn$ch=curl_init($requesturl);%5Cncurl_setopt($ch,%20CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,%20true);%5Cn$cexecute=curl_exec($ch);%5Cncurl_close($ch);%5Cn$twitch%20=%20json_decode($cexecute,true);%5Cnprint_r($twitch);%5Cn$display_name%20=%20$twitch['display_name'];%5Cn$game%20=%20$twitch['game'];%5Cn$status%20=%20$twitch['status'];%5Cn$url%20=%20$twitch['url'];%5Cn$avatar%20=%20$twitch['logo'];%5Cn$views%20=%20$twitch['views'];%5Cn$followers%20=%20$twitch['followers'];%5Cn?%3E)

Comment: This is my current code on testing the PHP and I dont see any results; https://pastebin.com/JakUHnnu